# Дизайн приложения под Android / iOs

Tags: android, ui, design

Я рисую в иллюстраторе приложения но вот всегда проблема с девелоперами. Когда нарезаю png для них то размер экспорта получается больше чем на скрине концепта. Как лучше рисовать? минимальный размер приложения а потом растягивать или же максимальный а потом уменьшать. В новой версии иллюстратора появился плагин который экспортирует но всегда почему то не в размер получается. Помогите всем чем сможете)))

Comment: А почему именно в PNG? Если вы работаете в Illustrator'e, то можно же экспортировать в формат SVG, а потом вставлять уже в среде разработки. В Androide даже легче использовать именно картинки в SVG формате, так как слишком большая периферия устройств, с различными экранами. :)

Comment: ПНГ потому что так требует девелопер)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте данный скрипт [mobile-export-scripts-illustrator](https://github.com/austynmahoney/mobile-export-scripts-illustrator)

Он позволяет экспортировать изображение в разных размерах, которые затем автоматически выбираются на устройстве в соответствии с размером его экрана

`├───Android
 │   ├───drawable-mdpi
 │   │   └───app-icon.png
 │   ├───drawable-hdpi
 │   │   └───app-icon.png
 │   ├───drawable-xhdpi
 │   │   └───app-icon.png
 │   ├───drawable-xxhdpi
 │   │   └───app-icon.png
 │   ├───drawable-xxxhdpi
 │   │   └───app-icon.png
 └───iOS
     ├───app-icon.png
     ├───app-icon@2x.png
     └───app-icon@3x.png`

Порядок установки и использования находится на странице проекта.

Comment: В новом илюстраторе есть плагин уже который экспортирует для айфонов и андроид но поччемуто размер не сосответсвует когда собирают приложение. вот и возник вопрос лучше рисовать минимальное а потом увеличивать ?

Comment: @Маис Тазагулян покажите пример, что получается, и что должно быть

Comment: к сожалению собраного приложения еще нету